# why using resample().interpolate('spine') create all nan?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with date gap, for example, 2023 10-02 10:00, 2023 10-02 10:10, then jump to next day of 2023 10-03 10:00,2023 10-03 10:10. Now I am using `resample('10min')` to create time series every 10min from 2021 01-01 to 2021 01-02, then using `interpolate(method="slinear", fill_value="extrapolate", limit_direction="both",order=2)` to fill missing date gap, however, the result is all of data become NaN.

so I am trying to understand why `interpolate()` create all NaN while `mean()` doesn't? Thanks for your help.

Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks

Here's the code

```
test_file='test_resample.csv'
df=pd.read_csv(test_file,sep='\t').set_index('Date')
df.tail(13)
    100 102 104
Date            
10/2/2023 9:43  202.7250    202.9100    203.3800
10/2/2023 9:52  203.3000    203.2250    203.5100
10/2/2023 10:01 203.2875    203.4000    203.7050
10/2/2023 10:10 202.7450    202.8000    203.7125
10/2/2023 10:19 203.0075    202.9925    202.8875
10/3/2023 7:49  205.7625    205.7000    206.1250
10/3/2023 7:59  205.4600    205.8675    205.8925
10/3/2023 8:08  205.7925    205.7325    205.9850
10/3/2023 8:17  205.5525    206.0225    205.8250
10/3/2023 8:26  205.7925    205.8000    206.2675
10/3/2023 8:35  205.8400    205.9250    205.9475
10/3/2023 8:44  204.1450    204.8400    205.0275
10/3/2023 8:53  204.2175    204.0425    204.3575
```

Now I am doing resampling and use interpolate to fill gap, you can see I got all NaN, why?

```
rule_1='20min'
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df_2=df.resample(rule=rule_1).interpolate(method="slinear", limit_direction="both",fill_value="extrapolate", order=2) 
df_2.tail(13)

    100 102 104
Date            
2023-10-03 04:40:00 NaN NaN NaN
2023-10-03 05:00:00 NaN NaN NaN
2023-10-03 05:20:00 NaN NaN NaN
2023-10-03 05:40:00 NaN NaN NaN
2023-10-03 06:00:00 NaN NaN NaN
2023-10-03 06:20:00 NaN NaN NaN
2023-10-03 06:40:00 NaN NaN NaN
2023-10-03 07:00:00 NaN NaN NaN
2023-10-03 07:20:00 NaN NaN NaN
2023-10-03 07:40:00 NaN NaN NaN
2023-10-03 08:00:00 NaN NaN NaN
2023-10-03 08:20:00 NaN NaN NaN
2023-10-03 08:40:00 NaN NaN Na
```

if I use `mean()` instead of `interpolate()`, some of data are still kept like this

```
rule_1='20min'
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df_1=df.resample(rule=rule_1).mean()
df_1.tail(13)
    100 102 104
Date            
2023-10-03 04:40:00 NaN NaN NaN
2023-10-03 05:00:00 NaN NaN NaN
2023-10-03 05:20:00 NaN NaN NaN
2023-10-03 05:40:00 NaN NaN NaN
2023-10-03 06:00:00 NaN NaN NaN
2023-10-03 06:20:00 NaN NaN NaN
2023-10-03 06:40:00 NaN NaN NaN
2023-10-03 07:00:00 NaN NaN NaN
2023-10-03 07:20:00 NaN NaN NaN
2023-10-03 07:40:00 205.61125   205.78375   206.00875
2023-10-03 08:00:00 205.67250   205.87750   205.90500
2023-10-03 08:20:00 205.81625   205.86250   206.10750
2023-10-03 08:40:00 204.18125   204.44125   204.69250
```

So why does `interpolate()` create all NaN, while `mean()` is different?

Comment: anyone ca nhelp? Thanks

Comment: As per Pandas documentation, fill_value is not a valid keyword for interpolate. Remove it and everything works fine with the example you provide. Cheers.

Comment: Hi Laurent, it doesn't work for me, not sure why? I am using pandas 2. are you using pandas 2? Thanks

Comment: Hi, I'm using Python 3.10 and Pandas 2.1.1. Cheers.